# Plotting two variables and grouping by classes using 3 different colors and symbols in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

I am having a hard time grasping plotting in matlab, when I run this line:

```
gscatter(wine1.Alcohol,wine1.Ash,wine1.Class,'br','xo')
```

It shows:

[image]

But I obviouly want the third class to be a different color, how can I do that?

Comment: If you are going to post a self-answered question, you should properly separate it into a 'question' and 'answered' part.

Comment: I've edited it into Q&A format for you now. For future self answers please do it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it with this:

```
gscatter(wine1.Alcohol,wine1.Ash,wine1.Class,'rgb','osd')
```

which gives me:

[image]

Awesome it works!